# Unable to load Lua Scripts to NodeMCU: Invalid node.chipid()

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

For all of these scenarios, I am able to  upload the firmware and monitor via serial usb. But after creating my first firmware, for all new firmware, I can't upload Lua scripts using the nodemcu-tool without getting the following:

**Error Message**

```
F:\Development\NodeMCU\helloworld>nodemcu-tool -p COM3 upload init.lua 
[NodeMCU-Tool]~ Unable to establish connection 
[NodeMCU-Tool]~ Invalid node.chipid() Response: 6935962
```

**Observations**

- Can reset the board using nodemcu-tool. Leads me to assume the baud rate is fine.
- Can see the file system being created from PuTTy after loading any of the firmware. Leads me to assume the firmware is OK.
- Have tried multiple dev boards, same results
- Found the source of the error message [device-info.js](https://github.com/AndiDittrich/NodeMCU-Tool/blob/master/lib/connector/device-info.js). either line 45 or 49
- I have no idea what "Response: 6935962" means. Is that my chip id or an error code?
- A new [commit](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/commit/310faf7fcc9130a296f7f17021d48c6d717f5fb6) was made to the firmware source during the last couple of days. No idea if this is relevant.
- Was hoping to get this resolved before I go down the Docker rabbit hole. Lazy. I know.

**9/6/2019** - created first firmware to start development

- Built a firmware using https://nodemcu-build.com/ with these modules (cron, file, gpio, i2c, mdns, mqtt, net, node, sjson, tmr, uart, wifi)
- Uploaded the firmare using [NodeMCU-PyFlasher-4.0](https://github.com/marcelstoer/nodemcu-pyflasher/releases/download/v4.0/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-4.0-x64.exe)
- **No issues with this firmware. I've been able to upload lua scripts and test them successfully. Even now, I can revert back to this firmware and use it without issues. I've even redownloaded this firmware from the original link, and it works fine.**

**9/7/2019** - created a new firmware to use adc and other goodies

- Built a firmware using https://nodemcu-build.com/ with these modules (adc, cron, file, gpio, i2c, mdns, mqtt, net, node, rtctime, sjson, tmr, uart, wifi)
- Uploaded the firmare using [NodeMCU-PyFlasher-4.0](https://github.com/marcelstoer/nodemcu-pyflasher/releases/download/v4.0/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-4.0-x64.exe)
- Having the problem described above.

**9/8/2019** - built firmware with minimal modules

- Built a firmware using https://nodemcu-build.com/ with these modules (file, gpio, net, node, tmr, uart, wifi)
- Uploaded the firmare using [NodeMCU-PyFlasher-4.0](https://github.com/marcelstoer/nodemcu-pyflasher/releases/download/v4.0/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-4.0-x64.exe)
- Having the problem described above.

**Platform & Tools**

- Windows 10
- Development board: [HiLetgo ESP8266 NodeMCU LUA CP2102 ESP-12E Internet WiFi Development Board Open Source Serial Wireless Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010N1SPRK)
- Firmware builder: https://nodemcu-build.com/
- Serial Monitor: PuTTy 0.72
- Firmware Loader: NodeMCUPyFlasher 4.0
- Lua script loader: nodemcu-tool 3.0.2

Comment: I removed the firmware download links as they're dead (only available for 24h). [PR #2886](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2886) that you also linked to concluded our multi-month upgrade to SDK 3.0. You can see all PRs that went into this at [the milestone](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/milestone/13?closed=1). Also note that NodeMCU-Tool has [no "official" support](https://github.com/AndiDittrich/NodeMCU-Tool#compatibility) for NodeMCU beyond 1.5.4.

Comment: Follow https://github.com/AndiDittrich/NodeMCU-Tool/issues/65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchDeviceInfo()` first calls `node.info()` at https://github.com/AndiDittrich/NodeMCU-Tool/blob/master/lib/connector/device-info.js#L9. Then it does an `if-else` to figure out whether it's running on ESP8266 or ESP32.

With the recent upgrade to SDK 3.0 `node.info()` was changed in [PR #2830](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2830). See documentation at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/node/#nodeinfo. It now returns values the script doesn't consider to be coming from ESP8266. The script then calls `node.chipId()` in the `else` branch. So, it's getting a chip id from ESP8266 but it is *expecting* one from ESP32. Hence, the exception.

> I have no idea what "Response: 6935962" means. Is that my chip id or an error code?

It's your chip id.

To cut a long story short: NodeMCU-Tool needs to be adjusted as laid out above to work with the current NodeMCU version.

Answer (score 0):

I cached the same issue from the recent cloud build(https://nodemcu-build.com/). It works when i switch back to the old ones. It looks like a problem of the build system or recent source code. You can switch to other build method and try use the older code.

Comment: Please read the comments of the OP. I was able to solve the problem by downloading the most recent source for nodemcu-tool from the repo.